# QTextEdit doesn't make new line when reaching field border

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a chat application, so there is a text box where user types in the content.
The TextEdit box, would resize dynamically every time, when i just pressed return, but when it reaches the end of the field, unfortunately, it just increases by a little automatically.

```
def func(self):
    self.msgtext = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.msgtext.setObjectName('msgtext')
    self.msgtext.setStyleSheet("#msgtext {background-color: black; color: yellow; font-size: 18pt; }"
    "#msgtext:highlight {color: red; }")
    self.msgtext.setMaximumSize(500, 32)
    self.msgtext.textChanged.connect(self.test)

def test(self):
    lines = self.msgtext.document().blockCount()
    self.msgtextplain = self.msgtext.toPlainText()
    self.msgtext.setMaximumSize(500, 30*lines)
```

So as seen, it would just increase every time by one line, but when it reaches the end of field, It does not actually make a new line, Just tries to increase it's size a bit.

I have tried counting the length of string and use the simple boolean to insert the new line, But it would not work, because:

> I had to put lowercase letter `f` `110` times, to reach the end of the
>   line.    However, i had to put uppercase letter `F` only `44` times, to reach
>   the end of the line.

How can i make field automatically insert new line, every time user reaches end of the field? Can i count the length of QTextEdit's string, all equally? even if it's uppercase or lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question since it actually involves measuring the text width and height given line breaks but also given possible word wrapping. All subject to constraints (i.e. the width)

My suggestion is not to count the number of new lines etc rather than to let `Qt` measure the [text bounding rectangle (link to Qt5)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2). So given the maximum width of `500` and a large enough height for a limiting rectangle you could do something like this:

```
font = self.msgtext.currentFont()
metric = QFontMetric(font)
rect = metric.boundingRect(0, 0, 500, 10000, 
                           Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.TextWordWrap,
                           self.msgtext.toPlainText())
```

the resulting height would be found in `rect`

```
rect.height()
```

Note, this is only a guide, it doesn't provide working code. Also it won't solve arising issues right away.